# Solve $z^2-2iz-3=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve $z^2-2iz-3=0$, but I don't understand why my method doesn't work ! So, $$\Delta =(2i)^2-4\cdot (-3)=-4$$
and thus $$z=\frac{2i\pm 2i}{2}=0\ \ or\ \ 2i$$
but they are both no solution... what's wrong here ?

Comment: $(2i)^2-4(-3)=-4+12=8$ I think

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have $(2i)^2-(4)(-3)=-4+12=8$

Answer (score 4):

*There lies some calculation mistakes in your work*. We have $\Delta = (2i)^2-4(1)(-3) = 4i^2+12 =-4+12=8$.

Thus, the roots are $\displaystyle \frac{2i \pm \sqrt{8}}{2} = \pm \sqrt{2}  + i$. Hope it helps.

Comment: Should be $\pm 4+i $

Comment: Should be $\pm \sqrt{2}+i$ since you forgot to take square root of discriminant.